# how to convert image to matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

i am interested how to convert given image into  matrix form  with  just numbers?for example let take following picture

[image]

as i know there exist in matlab  special functions,which  decompose given image into colors and numbers,for example i have seen  this code on this website

```
I = imread('test.jpg');
b = dec2bin(I); % b becomes vector
% some actions with binary vector
du = bin2dec(b);
du = reshape(du,size(I)); % converting vector du to 3d Image array 
imwrite(uint8(du), 'du.jpg'); %save our du to file du.jpg

I = imread('du.jpg'); %test if it saved correctly
imshow(du)
```

and converted to  my picture,like this

```
I=imread('tensor_in.jpg');

b=dec2bin(I)
```

and get the following  array,in fact only with zero and one

```
00001110
00001111
00010000
00010000
00010001
00010010
00010011
00010101
00010110
00011000
00011001
00011000
00010101
00010101
00010101
00010101
00010101
00010101
00010101
00010101
00011000
00011000
00011000
00011000
00011000
00011000
00011000
00011000
00011011
00011011
00011011
00011011
00011011
00011011
00011011
00011011
00011100
00011100
00011100
00011101
00011101
00011110
00011110
00011101
00011110
00011011
00011011
00011011
00100000
00100011
00101001
00101011
00101111
```

clearly i have not continued,because it's  size is

```
<151074x8 char>
```

and follows  same rule as for example

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

but  i am interested if instead of getting digital array,how to get array with some  another  numbers,like for example

```
2 1 3
4 21 23
67 89 100
```

let's say like this.could i do in matlab?please help me

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - are you saying that you want to get the RGB pixel values, as integers, in a list?

Comment: I = imread('test.jpg')

Did you try just this...
If its colour image, try I = rgb2gray(imread('test.jpg'))

Comment: i am interested if i can get some number's array from picture,maybe pixel values,but in fact  what i want is  to get such numbers,by which  this figure  can be created

Comment: i have used imread function yes,but second one i have not used

Comment: i think i have question with this part.b = dec2bin(I),can use  something like dec10bin?

Comment: as always strange cause of downvoting

Comment: i want to say something for these guys who are down voting without understand problem,please dont  disturb me,because i have asked question,which i  have now,everything is clear,what is reason for downvoting i  did not understand,could downvoter explain me?

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but I suspect the reason is that you are using `dec2bin()` without understanding what it does. The first line in the documentation for `dec2bin()` says "Convert decimal to binary number in string". If you don't want your numbers in binary, why are you using a function that does nothing but convert numbers to binary? `imread()` alone gives you exactly what you're asking for, as markotka says in the answer below.

Comment: yes but instead of downvoting just tell me,i am saying always  this.but

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dato, when you use

```
I = imread('test.jpg');
```

your image is already in an array form of numbers. Each "number" tells you part of the color information.

If the image file is in an indexed form you will get a NxM array (for an image of the size NxM).

If the image is not indexed, you will get an NxMx3 array, where each of the three NxM arrays corresponds, respectively to the red, green and blue channel.

i suggest you to study how matlab handles images: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/creating_plots/working-with-images-in-matlab-graphics.html

Comment: so for getting  any  real number except  0 and 1,i should add color information?

Comment: @dato You don't need to "add" anything. The color information is there in the NxMx3 matrix I. I(1,1,1) will give you the red component of pixel (1,1) and I(231,218,3) will give you the blue component of pixel (231,218).